# Difference between origLink and Link in RSS feedback xml File

Tags: c#, xml, rss, rss-reader

I am developing RSS Reader, and i am confused what is the difference between `<link>` and `<feedburner:origLink>` elements in xml file?, 
and which better to use when navigating to topic page?

```
<link>http://rss.sciam.com/~r/sciam/topic/environmental-policy/~3/PTd5RKuTV_0/</link>
<feedburner:origLink>http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/keeling-curve-co2-monitoring-project-draws-a-decent-donation/</feedburner:origLink>
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, `<feedburner:origLink>` is the original (canonical) link to the content, while `<link>` is the one that Feedburner wants you to use...

In practice, `<feedburner:origLink>` is only valid for Feedburner and your reader will likely have more feeds than just feedburner feeds, so your general use case would be to keep track of the standard `<link>` element. However, you may want to keep track of it, just in case the redirection dies at some point (if Feedburner goes away for example).

Also, I hear from Google employees that they never intended to expose `<feedburner:origLink>`. It was initially a bug, but once it got out there they could not take it back!